# VB replacing characters in attached csv

Tags: vb.net

I have a major problem that I just can't fix. I am picking a .csv with `OpenFileDialog`:

```
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a csv file"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "csv|*.csv"


    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
```

`Timer1` is basically just starting a process that converts the information from the csv into a data grid. So the thing I want to do next is to replace characters inside the csv with others and custom save this. But I can't find a clear solution. With File.IO I need to type in a specific path - I don't want this, I want to choose a specific file with the file dialog.

I tried using StreamWriter but I cant really replace and search with this. What am I missing? Does anyone have a good solution for this problem ?

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are **NOT** equivalent and do not run together. Please take care when tagging your questions. If you don't, there's a chance you won't get quick, accurate responses. Every tag provides a short info when you type it in - **read** those to be sure you're tagging correctly.

Comment: Read the file into a string, replace what you need and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to pass information somehow to your process.
However it can be simply done without the timer:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a csv file"
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "csv|*.csv"

If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim Content as string = File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)
    Content = Content.Replace("CharacterOld", "CharacterNew")
    File.WriteAllText(OpenFileDialog1.Filename, Content)
End If
```

I would also recommend not using a timer for your process unless it calls for data being checked every once in a while. if you want it to multi-thread this then I would recommend looking into .Net Tasks.:

```
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a csv file"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "csv|*.csv"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Task.Run(
            Sub(Filepath As String)
                Dim Content As String = File.ReadAllText(Filepath)
                Content = Content.Replace("CharacterOld", "CharacterNew")
                File.WriteAllText(Filepath, Content)
            End Sub, OpenFileDialog1.Filename)
    End If
```